# Naming a package built on TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, ctan, naming

I am working on a package which builds on TikZ. How should I name it — `tkz-foo` or `tikz-foo` (`foo` is a placeholder). In CTAN both styles can be found: [tikz-](http://www.ctan.org/search/?search=tikz&search_type=id) as well as [tkz-](http://www.ctan.org/search/?search=tkz&search_type=id). There are more `tkz-`named packages than `tikz-`named ones so I am inclined to go with that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Martin's answer aside, I think there's no reason to try to cram words into package names these days.  There was probably once an 8-character limit, so you got names like "fancyhdr" and "fncylab" (I don't know why the author limited themselves to 7 on that one).  Now, at the very least, "microtype" proves this is no longer a concern.  Since it makes the names unreadable and unmemorable, please don't do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `tikz` to refer to the actual TikZ package.
For example, I called my TikZ based timing diagram package `tikz-timing`.

All `tkz` package seem to be from the same author (which is also a TeX.SX user). 
The macros of these package seem to start with `tkz` prefix. Calling you package the same way suggest to users that it belongs to this set of packages and would kind of invade the "namespace" of another package author.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that all the `tkz-` packages are from the same author. `tikz-` it is. Thank you!